# why my query is not covered by the index with collation?

Tags: mongodb

i have the following collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b75cd077a764166f282d24"), "name" : "topolino" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61b75cdd77a764166f282d25"), "name" : "tòpolino" }
```

and the following indexes (notice that i set up a default collation at the collection level)

```
 db.collation.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "collation" : {
                        "locale" : "it",
                        "caseLevel" : false,
                        "caseFirst" : "off",
                        "strength" : 1,
                        "numericOrdering" : false,
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                        "maxVariable" : "punct",
                        "normalization" : false,
                        "backwards" : false,
                        "version" : "57.1"
                }
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "name" : 1
                },
                "name" : "name_1",
                "collation" : {
                        "locale" : "it",
                        "caseLevel" : false,
                        "caseFirst" : "off",
                        "strength" : 1,
                        "numericOrdering" : false,
                        "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
                        "maxVariable" : "punct",
                        "normalization" : false,
                        "backwards" : false,
                        "version" : "57.1"
                }
        }
]
```

then i run "explain" on the following query:

```
db.collation.find({name: "topolino"},{_id : 0, name:1}).sort({name:1}).explain("executionStats");
```

i expected the query to be covered, since it searches only the "name" field and i explicitly removed the "_id" field. But the explain method shows:

```
 "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
 "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
```

which means that it still needs a FETCH step after the IXSCAN

Anybody can explain this behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without collation it will work, with 0 docs examined.
But you are using collation `"it"`.

The index can say that it matches, but it doesn't really know the real value that it stored in the document, until it reads it.

I am not sure about this, but it looks logical to need to examine the docs also, because collation indexes don't have `1-1` matches to know the real stored value also.

This is expected with all indexes that can match 1 to many possible values.

Multikey indexes queries are not covered also, because the index, don't know the order of the members in the array, so again the docs are examined.